# MongoDB: Should sharding be enabled from the first day?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm new to Mongo as well as sharding.

Our app will be served by MongoDB and we expect billions of records to be stored. However, the db will grow slowly, ie it'll probably take years to reach that huge size.

Furthermore, we will mostly use a special encrypted value to look up records. This holds all the info needed to find the given record, ie the primary key, the shard key etc.

My question is: Should we enable sharding from the first day and encrypt shard key + PK? Or could we enable sharding later (when needed) and tell mongo to look up certain records (the ones whose encrypted ID holds no shard key) in the default, "unsharded" collection?

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you will use special encrypted value to look up records.  How is that different from a primary key or something you can use as a shard key later?

Comment: It is different because it holds multiple values. E.g: decoding something like sdhGhj3342K34334dd turns it into 3 integers: PK and other IDs. This is needed because the encrypted value is public, it will be used in links pointing to our app.

Comment: why would you need to add something to it for "shard key"?  why wouldn't you just use it "as is"?  I'm trying to understand your concern before answering.